# Angular2 progress circle package

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular2-material

I am using

> @angular2-material/progress-circle

for my project.How can I change  color of the progress circle ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the color attribute to set the color to `primary`, `accent` or `warn`. There is a guide [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/docs/theming.md) to creating a custom theme.